# One side page in a two side document in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am writing my thesis in a two sided document style. However I want the title page, certificate page and declaration page to be in a single sided format. How do I do this in LYX ?

I used standard report class.

Comment: At the menu bar you have: Insert > Formatting > Clear Double Page

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's not what he asked, I think.

Comment: Curious: To clarify, do you want symmetric margins for those pages?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. My thesis is double-sided and I've done: title-page - clear double page - dedication - clear double page - Table of contents - clear double page - rest of the thesis... and it works. Is it not correct? Why change the margin if all pages are bound at the end?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are correct. I want symmetric margins for these pages only. The rest of the pages are to be in double sided document format for which I have specified the outer and inner margins as given in univ. guidelines.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I didn't say your way is incorrect (on the contrary, I'd do the same), I said that isn't what was asked for, as the OP confirmed in his comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned briefly in a comment, I wouldn't do this I think. Keep the margins constant throughout.

That said, it looks like you can do this with the `geometry` package. You don't give any details about documentclass or how you set the margins, so this is a bit general. Seemed to work for my simple test with the `book` class.

1. Add the `geometry` package, one of two cases:

   - If you have changed the margins of your document via Document --> Settings --> Page margins, then LyX will already have added the `geometry` package to your document, so you don't have to do it yourself.
   - If not, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add `\usepackage{geometry}`
2. In Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, add `\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{hmargin=4cm}}`, changing `4cm` to whatever margin you desire.
3. In your document, right after the last thing that should have symmetric margins, add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or Insert --> TeX code), and type `\restoregeometry` in this inset.